# react native different stages in appstoreconnect

Tags: react-native, app-store-connect, testflight, staging

I am developing a react native application and want to bring it to the ios appstore.

Since I do have different stages in the backend I would like to have **also a dev version for the rn application that testusers can test via testflight**.

For Android we can easily create the applications within one "project" in the console, but for the appstoreconnect I do not see how to do this the best way.

**Do I have to create a second app on the appstoreconnect, to be able to distribute the dev version connected with dev backend? Or is there any better way?**

**Update** - to try explain my question better
**I have already explored flavours and environment files**, I am now purely looking at Testflight.

In Firestore for Android I can create one app that is android dev and one that is android prod, from there AND with environment files in place in my react native code, I can easily distribute dev for testing and then later on prod. That happens in the same project.

Now here comes the question, is there any way to do the same in the appstoreconnect to test dev in testflight and then later upload the code that is connected to prod and go live? Maybe I am just confused but in Testflight it looks like there can be only one version and that is the release version and no dev.

Or do I just upload DEV and QA builds(archives) and when everything has been tested and I want to go productive I upload all of a sudden the version that is connected to the prod backend?

Another idea that comes to my mind is to create one app MyApplication and one MyApplicationDEV in appstoreconnect, but that feels a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage different versions of the app using **Flavours (Android) and Scheme (iOS)**

In **Flavours (Android) and Scheme (iOS)**, you can make different versions of your app. For example for Quality Assurance Team, Dev Team, Client, and Production Team.  You can manage all the configurations using different `env` files.   There will be a separate env file for every **Flavour (Android) and Scheme (iOS)**

More information:  https://medium.com/@ujjwalsayami/build-flavor-scheme-for-react-native-c58e764d4ecf

If You Talk about the **Testflight** specifically, You can make their different

> Internal Groups (Only Appstore Connect users can join)(Pros: No need to wait for approval for Testflight testing)

and

> External Groups (Users outside Appstore connect can join via email invite)(Cons: Need to wait for approval for every new version on Testflight)

and add your dev team there.  They will get a build update on a **Testflight**.

Comment: Hey thanks for the already good answer. I guess I will have to make my question clearer. -> I am really only looking to testflight. Flavours and envs I did already explore.

Comment: I have explained the test flight process. if you have more question, pls let me know

Comment: Well you explained the basic flow in Testflight, but did not answer my question. I know that I can add internal and external Testers and that for the later I need to go through an approval by apple. - What I want is to have a dev version and a prod version. I want to have prod running while pushing changes and testing on dev. My question remains, do I need two apps in appstoreconnect for that?